# bootstrap 3 scaling text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've just started using bootstrap 3 and whilst playing with the layout I can't seem to get the text to scale on my mobile when within a jumbotron h1 tag. I'm trying to copy the jumbotron on the getbootstrap site which has large text that scales down when the viewport changes.

```
    <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
      <center><span class="h1">Testing Jumbotron </span></center>
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-5 btn-info btn btn-sm">Full</div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
</div>
```

I've just looked at an example and it seems the heading does scale within bootstrap 3 ... but maybe because I'm using flat-ui it has broken this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your html to this.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="row">
            <center><span class="h1 col-xs-10">Testing Jumbotron </span>

            </center>
            <div class="col-xs-2 btn-info btn btn-sm">Full</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Simplest way is to use dimensions in % or em. Just change the base font size everything will change.

```
@media (max-width: @screen-xs) {
    body{font-size: 10px;}
}

@media (max-width: @screen-sm) {
    body{font-size: 14px;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What i know, bootstrap can not scale down text automaticly if you don't do it your self in css.
Have you tried adding media queries.

Example

```
/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) {
.h1 {
font-size:20px;
}
 }
```